# Combining two lists of names and sorting them to make one sorted list of names

Tags: python, list, sorting

The problem that I am currently working on is this:

I want to write a function called combine(L1, L2) that takes two sorted lists as input, combines all the elements in the two lists into one sorted list, and then returns that list. For example,

```
    L1 = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Eve"]

    L2 = ["Adam", "Chloe", "David"]
```

The returned list would be

```
    ["Adam", "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Chloe", "David", "Eve"].
```

No built-in list methods other than append, not sorted function allowed.

This is what I have so far:

```
    def convertString(s):
        return s==str(s)

    def compareName(n):
        for i in n:
            if i[i]<="A":
                newList.append(i)
        return newList

    # This function combines two lists and produces a final sorted list.
    def combine(L1,L2):
        newList=[]
        L1=convertString(L1)
        L2=convertString(L2)
        for c in range(L1):
```

Comment: You can have a look at the merge subroutine from the merge-sort algorithm, which does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already figured it out, but this is one way you can go about it:

```
    L1 = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Eve"]
    L2 = ["Adam", "Chloe", "David"]

    def merge_sorted_lists(L1, L2):

        sorted_list = []

        # Copy both arg lists to make sure  original lists are not
        # modified
        l1 = L1[:]
        l2 = L2[:]

        while len(l1) > 0 and len(l2) > 0:
            if (l1[0] <= l2[0]): # Compare both heads
                item = l1.pop(0) # Pop from the head
            else:
                item = l2.pop(0)

            sorted_list.append(item)

        # Add the remaining of the lists
        sorted_list += l1 + l2

        return sorted_list

    # Output
    ['Adam', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Chloe', 'David', 'Eve']
```

This is pretty much an implementation of the merge-sort algorithm.